# The HTML code set as text and not parsed as html code

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the below call AJAX code in my JavaScript code:

```
$.get("MyServlet",function(data, status) {          
        $('#ajaxResponse').text(data);
});
```

`MyServlet` returns a piece of HTML code.

The content of my element `#ajaxResponse` is set as text and not as HTML code. When I inspect element I found the content of my div like this:

```
&lt;table border="1"&gt;
&lt;tr&gt;
    &lt;td&gt;ID&lt;/td&gt;
    &lt;td&gt;Name&lt;/td&gt;
    &lt;td&gt;Surname&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jQuery `.html()` method:

```
$.get("MyServlet",function(data, status) {          
    $('#ajaxResponse').html(data);
});
```

The jQuery `.text()` method escapes all HTML found in the data.

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: yes :) That is :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Use [`$().html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) instead.

[`$().text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) escapes every HTML tag.

From the docs:

> We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as
>   necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls
>   the DOM method .createTextNode(), does not interpret the string as
>   HTML.